# React form onSubmit not noticing the Enter button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a form including a sort of tag input. If a user inputs a tag and hits enter it will add the tag to a certain array. But, when I hit enter, it will also submitting the form. Ofcourse, I can add the `e.preventDefault()` trick but then again, it will still run the JavaScript code, something I don't want when I am trying to input a tag.

So I've tried to add a `if` statement to notice if the key is equel to enter but the form don't get notified which button is clicked, I guess.

So this function will run If I hit enter on the form.

```
handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Not working..
    if(e.keyCode === 32) {
        alert('Enter..') // prevent submitting further here or something
    } else {
        let state = { ...this.state.product }

        if (state.name == '' || state.price == 0 || state.ingredients.length <= 0) {
            alert('Naam, prijs en ingredienten zijn verplicht');
        } else {

            console.log(state);

        }
    }

}
```

How can I totally block the enter key for submitting? How can I use that key code for instance with a form or something? I've tried to add a event listener but that didn't work out since it will submit when I hit a other button than Enter.

For context, my tag input function which got fired from a keyup event.

```
handleKeyPress(e) {

    // if the event key == enter key (is working..)
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {

        // Check if there is a ingredient supplied
        if(this.state.tag == '') {
            alert('Vul een ingredient in')
        } else {

            // Get the value of the ingredient input
            let tag = this.state.tag;

            // Copy state of just the ingredients (not the product)
            let ingredients = [...this.state.product.ingredients];

            // Create an array including only the names of the ingredients
            let names = ingredients.map((item) => {
                return item.name;
            });

            // Check if the array already includes the ingredient
            if (names.includes(this.state.tag)) {
                // Alert if the ingredient already exists
                alert('Deze ingredient is al toegevoegd');
            } else {

                // Set the ingredient with value
                let ingredient = { name: tag, value: 1 };

                // Push the ingredient to the ingredients array of product
                ingredients.push(ingredient);

                // Get the product state
                let product = this.state.product;

                // set the ingredients of the product object with new ingredient
                product.ingredients = ingredients;

                // Change and set the state of proudct and empty out the tag input (ingredient)
                this.setState({ product: product }, () => {
                    this.setState({ tag: '' });
                });

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a form, it will always trigger `onSubmit` event when you hit enter, so assuming you want to use "enter" to keep adding tags, you can leave your add tags code in the submit function and add a button with `type="button"` (so the button wont submit on clicks) for when you are done with the form and use its `onClick` event to finish the form.

Example:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.handleDoneWithForm = this.handleDoneWithForm.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleDoneWithForm() {

  // Code for when the form is finished

}

handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Add tag code
}

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> // will be triggered on enter

      // form inputs

      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleDoneWithForm}> // will be triggered on click
        Done with form
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```